# Unity: Object is not being detected by raycast for highlighting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, selection, .obj

I followed this [tutorial](http://denis-potapenko.blogspot.com/2013/03/task-3-object-selection-and-highlight.html) on object selection. However, when I import my `.obj` assets and try to select/highlight them, it appears that the raycaster does not pick them up. Nothing happens when my mouse clicks on my .obj object. I added the necessary colliders (box collider even mesh collider) and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

I didn't change the code from the source provided. I just imported my object file to the scene and added the necessary physics.

All I want to do is highlight my `.obj` file via `onMouseDown`.

AppRoot.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class TransformObject
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Variables

    // variables

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    private float RotationSpeed = 1500;
    private float MoveSpeed = 50.0f;
    private float ZoomSpeed = 15.3f;
    #endif // UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

    public float MinDist = 2.0f;
    public float MaxDist = 50.0f;

    private Transform mMoveObject = null;

    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Public methods

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public TransformObject()
    {
        EnabledMoving = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets transform that will be used as "center" of the rotate / pan / zoom
    /// </summary>
    public void SetTransformRotateAround(Transform goMove)
    {
        mMoveObject = goMove;
        if (mMoveObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error! Cannot find object!");
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (!EnabledMoving)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 dir = mMoveObject.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
        float dist = Math.Abs(dir.magnitude);

        Vector3 camDir = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        Vector3 camLeft = Vector3.Cross(camDir, Vector3.down);
        Vector3 camDown = Vector3.Cross(camDir, camLeft);
        //Vector3 camUp = Vector3.Cross(camLeft, camDir);

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

        float dx = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float dy = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        // rotate
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            mMoveObject.Rotate(camLeft, dy * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            mMoveObject.Rotate(Vector3.down, dx * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
        }

        // move
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
            camPos += -camLeft * MoveSpeed * dx * Time.deltaTime;
            camPos += -camDown * MoveSpeed * dy * Time.deltaTime;
            Camera.main.transform.position = camPos;
        }

        // zoom
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            if (dist > MinDist)
            {
                mMoveObject.Translate(-dir * ZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
        {
            if (dist < MaxDist)
            {
                mMoveObject.Translate(dir * ZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }

    #endif // UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    }
    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or set value indicating if transformation is enabled
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnabledMoving
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets game object that moves around
    /// </summary>
    public Transform MoveObject
    {
        get
        {
            return mMoveObject;
        }
    }

    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

TransformObject.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class TransformObject
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Variables

    // variables

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    private float RotationSpeed = 1500;
    private float MoveSpeed = 50.0f;
    private float ZoomSpeed = 15.3f;
    #endif // UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

    public float MinDist = 2.0f;
    public float MaxDist = 50.0f;

    private Transform mMoveObject = null;

    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Public methods

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public TransformObject()
    {
        EnabledMoving = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets transform that will be used as "center" of the rotate / pan / zoom
    /// </summary>
    public void SetTransformRotateAround(Transform goMove)
    {
        mMoveObject = goMove;
        if (mMoveObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error! Cannot find object!");
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (!EnabledMoving)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 dir = mMoveObject.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
        float dist = Math.Abs(dir.magnitude);

        Vector3 camDir = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        Vector3 camLeft = Vector3.Cross(camDir, Vector3.down);
        Vector3 camDown = Vector3.Cross(camDir, camLeft);
        //Vector3 camUp = Vector3.Cross(camLeft, camDir);

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

        float dx = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float dy = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        // rotate
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            mMoveObject.Rotate(camLeft, dy * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            mMoveObject.Rotate(Vector3.down, dx * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
        }

        // move
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
            camPos += -camLeft * MoveSpeed * dx * Time.deltaTime;
            camPos += -camDown * MoveSpeed * dy * Time.deltaTime;
            Camera.main.transform.position = camPos;
        }

        // zoom
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            if (dist > MinDist)
            {
                mMoveObject.Translate(-dir * ZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
        {
            if (dist < MaxDist)
            {
                mMoveObject.Translate(dir * ZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }

    #endif // UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    }
    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or set value indicating if transformation is enabled
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnabledMoving
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets game object that moves around
    /// </summary>
    public Transform MoveObject
    {
        get
        {
            return mMoveObject;
        }
    }

    #endregion
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Constants.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Constants
{
    public const float cMaxRayCastDistance = 1000.0f;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, we have no idea if you followed that blog perfectly.  Nor will many people want to go to that site, dl the project, unzip the project, import the project, and debug it on their own machine.

Comment: For poops and giggles, follow Xerosigma's debugging suggestion and also change your `cMaxRayCastDistance ` to something large, like [Mathf.Infinity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Infinity.html).  We might as well rule out distance as an issue.

Comment: I'm the author of this blog, i also tried to import the *.obj file and it works fine. Please give me your the Unity3d project, and i can help you.

Comment: Denis Potapenko, where should I send you the project file? What email can I use?

Comment: Jerdak, it says, "The name 'Mathf' does not exist in the current context. (Error CS0103).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that "femur_left_1_7_dist/default" and "femur_left_1_7_prox/default" has no colliders. So there are two ways to resolve this issue:

1. In project view select "femur_left_1_7_dist" and "femur_left_1_7_prox", and in inspector in Import settings choose "Generate Colliders" and press "Apply" button:

   [image]
   OR
2. Select "femur_left_1_7_dist/default" in the scene and press "Component/Physics/Box Collider"; see the result here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20023505/stackoverflow_forum/s_fix.zip

Comment: I will take a look. For some reason, I thought I added a mesh collider to the object.

Comment: KalaJ, Ok. Please let me know about your results.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I didn't know I had to set "generate colliders" even though I added a box collider to the object.

Comment: Denis, I have one more question. When I try to import this project's scene into another project of mine, I get the following error and I'm not sure why: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: KalaJ, For using scene in another project you cannot just copy it, because in such a way the projects lost all references to scene objects, and this may cause such errors. You should create an empty prefab in your assets, then move all objects from the scene to this prefab, and then just press "Export package". Finally, import this package to another project. 

 If you still cannot understand how to export and import the packages, please let me know, i'll create the package for you, and give you a link.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several things causing this but here are a few things to check for.

- Make sure your GameObject has a Collider Component attached to it.
- Make sure the GameObjects layer is not set to Ignore Raycast.
- Make sure you are Raycasting form the right camera.

The tutorial seems to be using a default camera for the Raycast, make sure you have a Camera in the scene that has its Tag set to Main Camera.

Comment: How do I make sure that the gameobjects layer is not set to ignore raycast?

Comment: In the inspector while you have your object selected you should see a Layer control that includes a dropdown. Be sure it isn't set to ignore raycast. Unity manual: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Inspector.html

Comment: It's not set to ignore and my object has a collider. How do I confirm that I'm raycasting from my main camera?

Comment: The Ray should be coming from Camera.main. If you followed the tutorial it should already be set to that. Just make sure your Cameras Tag is set to Main Camera, you can see this in the inspector while you have the camera selected.

Comment: @KalaJ try Debug.LogWarning(rayCastedGO.name); right under this line: GameObject rayCastedGO = hit.collider.gameObject; If you don't see the name of your object come up, it's not being hit by the Raycast.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42677/discussion-between-xerosigma-and-kala-j)

Comment: Yes exactly, I tried to put Debug.LogWarning(rayCastedGO.name); but the name does not come up. It only comes up for the other objects. It is not being detected by Raycaster and I wonder why.

Comment: That most likely means there not no Colliders then.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code in a scene with three cubes (room0 to room2) and a plane (flat) and it worked fine.

But your code is bit weird tough, especially the **TransformObject** class. This class should be a **MonoBehaviour** (a script) and added as a **Component** to the same **GameObject** than your **AppRoot** script.

You can even make it automatic by using the [RequireComponentAttribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) on your **AppRoot** class.

Now then, why isn't your code working in your case ?

- Did you try to use the debugger while running your code, to see whether *SelectObjectByMousePos()* and *SelectedObject* got called at all?
- It is possible that the material you wanted to use isn't working with your meshes: try using your script with cubes (like I did) instead of your .obj
- Rewrite your code so that TransformObject is a **MonoBehaviour** script.

  - If you are concerned about **order of execution**, see this page : http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-ScriptExecution.html
- Check the collision matrix, maybe some layer to layer collision detection are disabled.

**edit:** does raycasting work with non-convex colliders?

Comment: Kryptos, Hi, that's very interesting indeed. I imported a basic cube and gave it the same material as in the example. I clicked on it and the raycaster detected the cube! The cube was selected just fine. However, for the .obj file, the raycaster could not detect it still.. This is interesting.

Comment: I have a guess. Did you put a MeshCollider on your .obj Mesh? Try again with a convex collider. It is possible that only convex colliders can catch raycasts!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I rewrite the code as a MonoBehaviour script?

Comment: Easy enough, your class must inherit from MonoBehaviour. Then you just add it to your GameObject as a component.