# How to handle click on object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've tried some examples of code to handle click on object, but they are don't work.

I have object's mesh on scene:
[image]

On Main Camera there is one C# Script Component with code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraAnim3 : MonoBehaviour
{

void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) { // if left button pressed...
            print ("cli!!!");
            //   create a ray passing through the mouse pointer:
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) { // if something hit...
                print ("clicked on object!!!");
                // if you must do something with the previously
                // selected item, do it here,
                // then select the new one:
                Transform selected = hit.transform;
                selected.gameObject.SetActive (true);
                print (selected.gameObject.name);
                // do whatever you want with the newly selected
                // object
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I clicked with left button on the mesh of head, in console message "cli!!!" showed, but no message "clicked on object!!!" was showed.

How to catch click on this mesh?

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read tag description before using it.

Comment: you dont have colider on the object

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here [Unity: Object is not being detected by raycast for highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431431/unity-object-is-not-being-detected-by-raycast-for-highlighting?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The modern to detect collisions is to implement [`IPointerClickHandler`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface, and ensure that you have an EventSystem and a relevant Raycaster (2d or 3d, depending on what collider are you using) present in the scene. It's much better than writing your own code to manage clicks and pointer positions. Also, the game object itself has to have a `Collider` component. It can either be a mesh collider, or a more generic (and better for performance) box collider.